# Reading Value form ConfigMap that are mounted as file in Kubernetes cluster JAVA

Tags: kubernetes, java-io, configmap

Here is my ConfigMap

---

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  application_config.properties: |-
    id= abc
    mode= abc
    username= abc
    endpoint: abc
    url= abc
    id= abc
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: yml-config
```

and here is my deployment

```
   ---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
....
spec:
....
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: demo
      name: demo
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: abc:1.0
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        name: demo
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 650Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 500m
            memory: 650Mi
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /opt/config/application_config.properties
          subPath: application_config.properties
          name: application-config-volume           
      ........
      volumes:
      - name: application-config-volume
        configMap:
          name: yml-config
```

What I need is -> I wish to mount my configmap as a single properties file in the mentioned location and just wish to read the values in core java by doing some I/O usage.

But I tried many ways used subpath, items and keys tag too. But I am only getting File not found exception.

(point to note - I dont have the access to look into the container which is creating some issue )
It would be great if someone could help me along with the java code showing how to fetch the value based on the mount path. Which I may try.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the code that tries to access this file look like?  What's the actual error or exception you get?  Have you tried reproducing this setup in a potentially more flexible local Kubernetes installation like [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/)?

Comment: Properties configProp = new Properties();
         try {
          configProp.load(new FileReader("/opt/kafka-config/application_config.properties"));
   } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

but it always fails with file not found, and I tried to debug the issue event after mounting config map as volume mount. some how its not getting mounted to the specific path.

Comment: Nothing is getting mount at "mountPath: /opt/config/application_config.properties"
I tried both the approach 1) to mount the whole file as single file 2) to mount files in which the number of files will be equal to the keys in your config map. Nothing seems to be mounting the data. God knows whats the issue.

Comment: This should be working, i did the same way. Can you try removing subpath? Also should you use that file as environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any function or command that is used to read file at that location